# How do I print the default value in Java without adding the default parameterized value in Oracle Function?

Tags: java, oracle

My Oracle Script:

```
function emir_ilet_p(p_customer_no number,p_buy_sel varchar2,p_kontrat varchar2, p_miktat number,p_fyt_tipi varchar2 default 'PYS',p_fiyat number default 0,p_record_no number default null ) return varchar2;
```

My Java Code:

```
  CallableStatement  stmt;    
         try {
            
            stmt = Sv.connection.prepareCall("? = call PKG_VIOP_SO.emir_ilet_p(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt.setInt(1, 11111);
            stmt.setString(2, "S");
            stmt.setString(3, "Test");
            stmt.setInt(4, 2);
            stmt.execute();
                        
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I want to send to Oracle default last 3 parameters. How Can I do this?  I'am gettin sqlException with this code.

Comment: what sql error are you getting?

Comment: @Szprota21  java.sql.SQLException: Index where IN or OUT parameter is missing :: 5

Comment: You are getting this exception because you only set values of 4 parameters. try to set all of them, default ones with null value

Comment: @Szprota21 man I know I set values of 4 parameters. But if I send a null value, won't a null value go to Oracle?

Comment: I'm not 100% but it should work like that
1. You send null to oracle function
2. Because parameter is null the default value will be used

Answer (score 0):

We can call `procedures` and `functions` using named notation for their parameters which is standard and recomended way of calling if I am working with oracle PL/SQL.

So in similar way we can construct the query string and call. I put the string into one variable so in case you have any standard way of creating strings using StringBuilder you can do so.

try below and see if it works for you,

```
CallableStatement  stmt;    
try {
    String functionCallString = "{ ? = call PKG_VIOP_SO.emir_ilet_p( p_customer_no => ?, p_buy_sel => ?, p_kontrat => ?, p_miktat => ? ) }";   
    stmt = Sv.connection.prepareCall(functionCallString);
    stmt.setInt(1, 11111);
    stmt.setString(2, "S");
    stmt.setString(3, "Test");
    stmt.setInt(4, 2);
    stmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At this very moment with my experience I know this way and not sure if any elegant solution is available using JDBC.